# Is it normal for database connections to spike like this?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, express, sequelize.js

Check out this graph of my database connections. I am running a Postgres database on Lightsail, and I am connecting to it from a single Ubuntu instance running a single instance of Express and Sequelize. I am a little confused by the spike in database connections.

You can see that in the past it has spiked to nearly 400. I haven't experienced any performance issues, and when I look at the CPU utilization over the same period, there is nothing concerning. But still I am wondering if the number of connections is normal. From my very dumb understanding of the issue, I am using Sequelize as an ORM, and I am using the default connection pool of 5, so it seems to me that there would only ever be up to 5 simultaneous connections.

[image: Database connections]

Comment: I am also currently experiencing this with AWS at the moment and a MySQL database, we have been getting alarms pretty often.. It's certainly odd.

Comment: It seems that it really depends upon the Express code that accesses the database.  If you're somehow executing a lot of parallel requests (each with their own connection) or not properly releasing connections that could lead to spikes.

Comment: If this were my project, I'd start logging everywhere I create a database connection in my Express server and start to understand where they are all coming from.

Comment: @c00kie over on serverfault someone pointed out that it's the "sum of database connections," not concurrent connections. It still seems odd.

Comment: @Glenn One of the tools we use creates a proxy tunnel between our main server and the database server. I don't know if you're doing the same, but it sounds like we're both having the same issue; a 'sum' of established connections rather than concurrent. The difference being that an established connection can sit there waiting forever while a concurrent connection drops out when finished. Let me know if you figure it out, it is giving me a headache. AWS alerts are extremely annoying as well but necessary.